# Improper Integral Convergence involving $e^{x}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm attempting to prove that
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}\,dx$
converges. Easily I was able to write,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3x}}{x}\,dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-7x}}{x}\,dx$$
and then I was going to use substitution on each of the integrals to find its value. The problem is, do these integrals need converge at the same rate? So do I have to make the same substitution for both integrals? If not, I'm not quite sure how I could go about solving this guy...

Comment: To write a convergent integral as the difference of two divergent integrals is not a good idea for proving convergence. Have a look at Frullani's theorem. It is $\log(7/3)$.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to prove that each of integrals congerge. And that's easy: if $x>1$, then $\frac{e^{-3x}}x<e^{-3x}$ and $\frac{e^{-7x}}x<e^{-7x}$. This is all you need to prove that both of them converges.

Comment: But isn't it divergent?

Comment: No. Why do you think that?

Comment: Well, $\Gamma(0)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x$ does not exist.

Comment: Ahh, but the original integral $\exists$, right?

Comment: Did you miss the $x>1$ from my answer?

Comment: No, I've missed the fact that $\nexists \int f, \int g$ does not mean that $\nexists \int f+g$

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral), where $f(x)=e^{-x}$:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}\,dx=\ln(7/3).$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}=4,
\end{align*}
so for a small $\eta>0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
0<\dfrac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}<3,~~~~x\in(0,\eta),
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\eta}\dfrac{e^{-3x}-e^{-7x}}{x}dx\leq 3\eta<\infty.
\end{align*}
Now for large $M>0$, for all $x>M$,
\begin{align*}
e^{3x}&>x\\
e^{7x}&>x,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\int_{M}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-3x}}{x}dx\leq\int_{M}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
similarly
\begin{align*}
\int_{M}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-7x}}{x}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
so 
\begin{align*}
\int_{M}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-3x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx
\end{align*}
converges.